# "How to change Rest response”

Tags: spring-boot

i'm trying to get json response from my rest api but i'm getting this format !

I used @RestController annotation and i'm geting "_embedded" !! i don't know how to change that because in my front application i can't use this format !

```
      @RestController
      public class HeroRestController {


 @Autowired
 private HeroRepository HeroRepo;


 @GetMapping("/heroes")
    public List<Hero> getMessage(){
        return HeroRepo.findAll();
    }
}
```

What i'm getting :

```
    {
       "_embedded" : {
           "heroes" : [ {
              "name" : "hero11",
                "_links" : {
           "self" : {
       "href" : "http://localhost:8009/heroes/2"
        },
    "hero" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8009/heroes/2"
    }
  }
     }, {
      "name" : "hero22",
      "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8009/heroes/3"
    },
    "hero" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8009/heroes/3"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## SPRING HATEOAS (HateoasProperties)

Use `spring.data.rest.defaultMediaType = application/json`  OR

`spring.hateoas.use-hal-as-default-json-media-type=true` 
in `application.properties` file. For more Spring data rest HATEOS , refer 
[SPRING HATEOAS (HateoasProperties)](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html)

Comment: i got this format : { "links" : [ { "rel" : "self",
    "href" : "http://localhost:8009/heroes{?page,size,sort}",  "hreflang" : null, "media" : null, "title" : null,  "type" : null,  "deprecation" : null  }, {  "rel" : "profile",
    "href" : "http://localhost:8009/profile/heroes",
    "hreflang" : null,
    "media" : null,
    "title" : null,
    "type" : null,
    "deprecation" : null
  }, {
    "rel" : "search",
    "href" : "http://localhost:8009/heroes/search",
    "hreflang" : null,
    "media" : null,
    "title" : null,
    "type" : null,
    "deprecation" : null
  } ],